# Is using element Id's to store variable information a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery/JavaScript and web development and am wondering what the best practices are for storing variables on a page.

Let's say I have a list that is populated from an Ajax call. Can I store a unique value returned from the Ajax call as the id of these list items? I want to be able to perform another Ajax call when an item is clicked and use the id for the lookup in the database. Is this OK to do or is there some other way that's considered best practice?

```
<ul>
<li id ="f5e218b6-6651-5c0a-829c-340e92d84679"></li> <!--Look up something when this is clicked -->
<li id ="l4e218b3-6631-5caa-529a-67a940589038"></li> <!--Look up something when this is clicked -->
</ul>
```

Comment: If you only need the `id`, it's fine. For more information, you should use data attributes, e.g. `<li data-price="9.99">`.

Comment: Use data attributes instead of id.  This will avoid potential issues later depending on what is trying to use ids directly.

Comment: I would avoid the use of “id” here as there is no _shown usefulness_ to use it for a selector: just leave the elements without any “id”. It is the “id” attribute of the element, not backing data - the association to backing data can be established using other methods with less conflation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the id and you may to need to select elements using it, it's fine. If you need to store more information about the elements, you should consider using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), as they avoid possible conflicts with new HTML attributes and do not require abusing other attributes.

For example, to store the price of an item, your markup could look like this:

```
<li data-price="9.99">Some product</li>
```

Comment: Not really sure why it’s “fine” to use ID to replace data-prod-id (ie. there is only one piece of attached meta-data, which arguably shouldn’t change the answer). The core issue, IMOHO, is conflating of presentation and data. What if there are multiple elements (maybe a full list and top-10 list) with items that refer to the _same_ backing data?

Comment: @user2864740 We don't know that the reverse lookup from data to element wouldn't be needed which would totally justify setting the element id property with these unique values. Note OP said they are unique

Comment: 1) Uniqueness and a reverse lookup is immaterial to separation of concerns muddled with using an element ID. 2) Design choices now impact design choices later.

Comment: “CAN” (eg. does this work) and “SHOULD” (eg. not a ‘bad idea’) are different beasts.

Comment: @user2864740 Certainly entitled to your opinion...I personally voted to close as opinion based. Quite common to have element id's relate to some other data structure.

Comment: So easy to blow off arguments as ‘opinion’.. this disregards any such validity (or lack of) while negating to address raised concerns.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way of information like those in a data attribute

E.g.

```
<li data-info="yourdatahere" >
```

the data attribute can be anything, data-size, data-myid etc

If the data is unique then you can store it in id attribute. But in future you may come up to a point where the information is same, that where the data- attribute is useful

Comment: In addition to uniformity with future flexibility, a separate attribute also promotes separation of concerns. I would only use the ID if the DOM element itself was required to be looked by ID (the question makes no mention of this being a case), and maybe not even then..